# hiding an indicator in certain time frames

Tags: pine-script

I made a simple pine script to draw lines for yesterday high/low and 2 days ago high/low.

```
study("YY H/L", overlay=true)

plot(security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]), title="Yhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#4caf50, linewidth=2)
plot(security(tickerid, 'D', low[1]), title="Ylow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#4caf50, linewidth=2)
plot(security(tickerid, 'D', high[2]), title="YYhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ff9800, linewidth=2)
plot(security(tickerid, 'D', low[2]), title="YYlow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ff9800, linewidth=2)
```

I'd like to hide this indicator when I switch to the Daily time frame, is that possible?

Comment: Why don’t you just use the hide button?

Answer (score 0):

Please include the version of Pine you are using in your code snippets. Since you are referring to series history with `[1]` and `[2]`, it's also safer to use lookahead on.

This will hide the plots on all timeframes higher than intraday (>=1D). If you only want to hide them on the daily timeframe, replace `isintraday` with `not isdaily`:

```
//@version=3
study("YY H/L2", overlay=true)
plot(isintraday ? security(tickerid, 'D', high[1],  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : na, title="Yhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#4caf50, linewidth=2)
plot(isintraday ? security(tickerid, 'D', low[1],   lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : na, title="Ylow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#4caf50, linewidth=2)
plot(isintraday ? security(tickerid, 'D', high[2],  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : na, title="YYhigh", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ff9800, linewidth=2)
plot(isintraday ? security(tickerid, 'D', low[2],   lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : na, title="YYlow", trackprice=true, offset=-99999, color=#ff9800, linewidth=2)
```